# Wildfly does not see .xhtml extension

Tags: maven, jsf, wildfly

I am using jdk 11 and wildfly 18. After I create a dynamic web project , i am converting to maven project it . Then I am adding below to pom.xml , I am working the project then I am taking 404 not found . WebContent has a NewFile.xhtml.Then i am running the project in wildfly but it does not work . Actually my project is working before convert to maven project . After convert it , project it does not work .Url extension : http://localhost:8080/JSFWeek02/welcome.xhtml . After I ran the project automatically url extension is that : http://localhost:8080/JSFWeek02/faces/welcome.xhtml . I do not know why I am taking a error . I will be happy if you help me about that.

web.xml

```
<project xmlns="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0"
    xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
    xsi:schemaLocation="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0 https://maven.apache.org/xsd/maven-4.0.0.xsd">
    <modelVersion>4.0.0</modelVersion>
    <groupId>JSFWeek01</groupId>
    <artifactId>JSFWeek01</artifactId>
    <version>0.0.1-SNAPSHOT</version>
    <packaging>war</packaging>
    <build>
        <sourceDirectory>src</sourceDirectory>
        <plugins>
            <plugin>
                <artifactId>maven-compiler-plugin</artifactId>
                <version>3.8.1</version>
                <configuration>
                    <release>11</release>
                </configuration>
            </plugin>
            <plugin>
                <artifactId>maven-war-plugin</artifactId>
                <version>3.2.3</version>
                <configuration>
                    <warSourceDirectory>WebContent</warSourceDirectory>
                </configuration>
            </plugin>
        </plugins>
    </build>


    <dependencies>
        <!-- https://mvnrepository.com/artifact/com.sun.faces/jsf-impl -->
        <dependency>
            <groupId>com.sun.faces</groupId>
            <artifactId>jsf-impl</artifactId>
            <version>2.2.20</version>
        </dependency>
        <!-- https://mvnrepository.com/artifact/com.sun.faces/jsf-api -->
        <dependency>
            <groupId>com.sun.faces</groupId>
            <artifactId>jsf-api</artifactId>
            <version>2.2.20</version>
        </dependency>

    </dependencies>

</project>
```

NewFile.xhtml

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="ISO-8859-1" ?>
<!DOCTYPE html PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD XHTML 1.0 Transitional//EN" "http://www.w3.org/TR/xhtml1/DTD/xhtml1-transitional.dtd">
<html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml" xmlns:h="http://java.sun.com/jsf/html">
<head>
<meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=ISO-8859-1" />
<title>Shen</title>
</head>
<body>
    
    I am <h:outputText value="Kerem"/>
    
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: I did not never use in Payara.

Comment: You're not supposed to provide JSF along with the webapp when server already provides JSF by itself. Much better is to restart from scratch just in order to ensure that everything is understood and done right: [JSF 2.3 tutorial with Eclipse, Maven, WildFly and H2](https://balusc.omnifaces.org/2020/04/jsf-23-tutorial-with-eclipse-maven.html)